# How should I use ScalaMeter for my project?

Tags: scala, scalameter

I've read ScalaMeter [docs](https://scalameter.github.io/home/gettingstarted/0.7/configuration/index.html) and I don't understand how can I use it for benchmarking my project and not some atom hardcoded operations. Imagine I have the simple project

```
object SumBenchmark {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val lst = List.fill(10000000)(1)
    lst.map(x => x + 1)
    val sum = lst.sum
  }
}
```

How can I use ScalaMeter to bench it? I mean something like

```
performance of "SumBenchmark" in {
    measure method "main" in {
      // I don't know what to write here but here should be some implementation of benchmarking
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Do I get it correctly that you want to benchmark doing an increment for all numbers in a list and then do the sum of the all the outupts?

Comment: I'd start by creating the `SumBenchmark` `object` inside `src/test/scala` with something like https://gist.github.com/mfirry/b393ed386e276190575780cd5202a55a and then you run it with `sbt test` or `sbt testOnly *SumBenchmark`

Comment: @mfirry the point is i want to benchmark the perfomance of code contained in object. Summation of list is a minimum reproducable example. So your example is not very helpful because I want to say to ScalaMeter "measure this object" somehow. Imagine that SumBenchmark is a black box and I want to measure how is it working

Comment: Right... then my guess would be instead of having ` r.map(_ + 1).sum` (for example in the link I provided) you would have a call to your logic you want to measure (say `mypackage.myObject.myFunc`)

Comment: Have a look https://github.com/mfirry/so-65682326

Comment: Thanks it was very helpful. Can you also say me if ranges values denote hoy many times tests are carried?

Comment: That should be covered by ScalaMeter docs

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the usual Scala projecct structure

```
├── build.sbt
└── src
    ├── main
    │   └── scala
    │       └── myPackage
    │           └── MyThing.scala
    └── test
        └── scala
           └── myPackage
               └── MyThingBench.scala
```

You basically put the logic you want to measure in the `MyThingBench` file

```
measure method "myfunction" in { myPackage.MyThing.myfunction() }
```